# How to fix SyntaxError in a module that gives an error upon import?

Tags: python-3.x, module

I'm making a discord bot, and every time I try to import discord.py, I get a syntax error.

```
import discord.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>

    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 38, in <module>

    from .state import ConnectionState
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 36, in <module>

    from . import utils, compat
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\compat.py", line 32
    create_task = asyncio.async
                              ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are experiencing this issue with your import statement is due to the fact that `discord.py` doesn't support Python 3.6 or above at the moment: you need to run your bot with Python 3.4 or 3.5. You can see this information at the beginning of the README file [on the GitHub repository](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py). You are getting a "syntax error" because `async` is now a reserved keyword in Python3.6+. This has nothing to do with your code, again it's your version of Python that is unsupported.

If you must use Python 3.6 or above, you can have a look at the *rewrite* version of `discord.py`. [Here is the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/) you might be looking for.